# Simple ring without identity (Commutative Algebra by Zariski & Samuel p 133)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative simple ring. If $R$ is not a field (equivalently, $R$ has no identity), there exists a nonzero element $a\in R$ such that $Ra\neq R$.

This statement appears in the page 133 of the book "Commutative Algebra" written by Oscar ZARISKI and Pierre SAMUEL. It seems not very hard to show it, but I am a bit confused. I shall be grateful if there is any expert who may share the ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't get a copy of the problem in the book fast, but I suspect you have misunderstood something. Here are the most relevant lines of thought.

If $R$ is commutative, then $aR$ is an ideal, and then there are only two possibilities for any given element $a\in R$: either $aR=\{0\}$ or $aR=R$.

If $R$ has identity, then $aR=\{0\}$ iff $a=0$ and $aR=R$ iff $a\neq 0$.

For a commutative simple ring$^\ast$ $R$ (not assuming identity anymore), if there is one single element $a$ such that $aR=R$, then $R$ has identity. For, there would exist $e$ such that $ae=a$, and for an arbitrary $b$, $as=b$. But then $be=ase=as=b$, showing $e$ is an identity.

So the only possibility is that $aR=\{0\}$ for every single $a\in R$, which *does* satisfy what you wrote, but in a rather extreme way. Under such conditions, every subgroup of $R$ is an ideal. It follows that $|R|=p$ for some prime $p$, and $ab=0$ for every $a,b\in R$.

$^\ast$ meaning a ring with only trivial ideals. Actually, simple rings without identity are usually additionally required to satisfy some nondegeneracy condition like $R^2\neq \{0\}$ or $R^2=R$. With that additional assumption, this problem statement becomes untenable.

Comment: In the question it is stated $R$ has no identity

Comment: @Find_X  Perhaps you should read the *entire* answer. There isn't any harm in commenting on what happens in that special case and it is necessary groundwork to show that $aR=\{0\}$ for all $a\in R$

Comment: @rschwieb Perfect answer!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: As far as I remember, little Herstein requires $R^2\ne\{0\}$ for simple rings.

Comment: @Find_X I don't understand why you're so bothered by this. It seems perfectly reasonable to me to highlight what happens when $R$ has an identity to explain the assumption.

Comment: @Find_X In the first sentence I mention that I think that there is something misunderstood about the problem statement. Chasing all of the possibilities to their end, which doesn't take much work in this case, demonstrates why I think the question is misstated somehow.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I would not be surprised if that's the case, and if so, adds to the soup of questions around the statement of this problem.

Comment: okay I understand

Comment: @TrevorGunn; I have no intentions to underestimate @rschweib's answer; I only wanted to clear my doubts

Comment: @rschwieb No, the question is not misstated. What I want to know is just the case when $R$ is without identity. Actually, you give a more precise answer: all the nonzero elements $a\in R$ satisfy that $Ra\neq R$, so $Ra=0$.